# Wrap everything beyond 3rd div in another div

Tags: jquery

I need to place a wrapper around all modules past the 2nd module.

```
<div class="show">
    <div class="module">some content</div>
    <div class="module">some content</div>
    <div class="module">some content</div>
    <div class="module">some content</div>
</div>
```

What I need is

```
<div class="show">
    <div class="module">some content</div>
    <div class="module">some content</div>

     <h4 class="more">View More</h4>
    <div class="show-more">
        <div class="module">some content</div>
        <div class="module">some content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can count the number of modules but I'm not sure how to append/prepend the html to the divs beyond the 1 index.

```
$('.show').each(function(i) { 
        var n = $(this).children('.module').length;
    });
```

I should mention that I multiple "show" divs that each need have their own modules.  So it needs to happen on each "show" div seperately.  A loop maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.slice` :

```
$('.module').slice(2).wrapAll('<div class="show-more" />');
$('.show-more').before('<h4> Show more </h4>')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tBq5U/1/

- [Slice](https://api.jquery.com/slice/)
- [Wrap All](https://api.jquery.com/wrapall/)
- [Before](https://api.jquery.com/before/)

---

Multiple module :

```
$('.show').each(function(){
    $(this).find('.module').slice(2).wrapAll('<div class="show-more" />')
    .parent().before('<h4> Show more </h4>');
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tBq5U/2/

Comment: What is the purpose of `slice`, if `wrapAll` wraps the elements?

Comment: @chadiusvt you dont want to wrap the first 2 elements. Slice start to index 2 so element 0 and 1 are removed.

Comment: Oh I got it, you remove the first 2 and wrap the remainder.  Essentially the same as `:gt()` selector.  Cool.

Comment: Essentially yes, but slice is faster. *-my comment about the child thing was false-*

Comment: This works perfect.  I updated my question though.  I have multiple "show" divs, each with their own module.

Comment: Dang, I keep trying to be faster, but we publish at essentially the same time, haha.

Comment: Haha, well thank you both for the help fast help.  I knew I would need to wrap it in a each loop but didnt realize it was simple as... wrapping it in an each loop.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the jQuery `wrapAll()` method, in conjunction with the `:gt()` selector.

The `:gt()` selector selects elements greater than a certain index, in your case `1` (0 based counting)

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SPGGF/4/)** example.

**UPDATED** to include new information about separate `.show` divs:

See code below:

```
$(".show").each(function (i, v) {
    $(v).children(":gt(1)").wrapAll("<div class='showMore'/>");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".show").each(function() {
    $(".module:gt(1)", this)
            .wrapAll('<div class="show-more" />')
            .first()
            .parent()
            .before('<h4 class="more">View More</h4>');
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rs8VJ/)

Comment: Updated according the new requirement (multiple `.show` divs)